# Evaluate generated math expression on a string with exponent i.e. (1+2-3)*4^5 = answer

Tags: c#

I have a generated math expression on a string and I'm using [codingseb expression evaluator](https://github.com/codingseb/ExpressionEvaluator) to evaluate it. It's great that it can evaluate basic operators and parenthesis but I can't use it to evaluate string with exponent. e.g. `1+2-5^7`

```
string a = "2+3^4-2";
int result;

ExpressionEvaluator e = new ExpressionEvaluator();     
var mathExpressionResult = e.Evaluate(expression);
result = (int)mathExpressionResult;
```

I expect the result to be 81, but the actual output is 7

Is there a way for this to work? Any alternatives?

Comment: [From the docs](https://github.com/codingseb/ExpressionEvaluator/wiki/Getting-Started), looks like the syntax is `Pow(x, y)` not `x^y`.

Comment: There seem to be two irrelevant parts that could be removed from this question; "random generated" and Unity3D don't make any difference to this question.

Comment: Yes it is. But what I'am looking for is how to use that with my code given that the string value is generated

Comment: Right, so you're asking how to turn "2+3^4-2" into "2 + Pow(3, 4) - 2"?

Comment: @canton7 I would expect that to be `2 + Pow(3, 4) - 2`, if operator precedence is observed.

Comment: @canton7 - I don't think `5^4-2` is 81. `3^4` is, which suggests higher precedence.

Comment: D'oh, fat fingers. Corrected.

Comment: It should be 81. 2 + (3^4) -2 with BODMAS is (3^4) = 81 then +2 -2=81

Comment: @reckface yes, the question says it should be 81

Comment: Solved it. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer! First i thought that "2 + Pow(3, 4) - 2" is wrong because i keep getting InvalidCastException. Then after resting a bit and reviewing my code again, found out the problem is `result = (int)mathExpressionResult;`. `Pow(x,y)` returns a double value therefore it should be `result = (double)mathExpressionResult;`

```
string a = "2+ Pow(3,4)-2";
double result;

ExpressionEvaluator e = new ExpressionEvaluator();     
var mathExpressionResult = e.Evaluate(expression);
result = (double)mathExpressionResult;
```

Thanks for the other answers!

Comment: It is great the you told us what worked. In fact you don't need to declare it as double or use casts - See @Emiel Koning answer.

Answer (score 1):

This gives me an 81...

```
using System;
using CodingSeb.ExpressionEvaluator;                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
      string expression ="2 + Pow(3, 4) - 2";

        ExpressionEvaluator evaluator = new ExpressionEvaluator();

        Console.WriteLine("Result "+ evaluator.Evaluate(expression));
    }
}
```